# Checking destination directory after "No space left on device" error

Tags: rdiff-backup

My latest backup attempt with `rdiff-backup` failed due to `"[Errno 28] No space left on device"`. And it's true, according to `du` there are 0 bytes available on the backup device.

When I now try to revert the directory to the state before the unsuccessful session by simply starting another backup attempt, I also get `[Errno 28]`. The next idea I had was to get rid of some old backup increments to gain some fresh disk space.

To see the list of backup increments, I invoked `rdiff-backup -l mirror_dir` which results in

```
Fatal Error: Previous backup to mirror_dir seems to have failed.
Rerun rdiff-backup with --check-destination-dir option to revert directory to state before unsuccessful session.
```

Then I did what the message told me and ran `rdiff-backup --check-destination-dir mirror_dir` which again gives me the now already famous `[Errno 28]`. It seems like I am in a dead end, where I cannot do *anything* anymore, not even free some disk space which action seems to be the only solution to this problem.

Is there a way out of this situation?

Comment: You cannot manually delete stuff?

Comment: You mean that I should remove the old increments manually? How would one do that?

Comment: Does this volume contain only backups ? Are there no other files there that could go ? Also, rdiff-backup sometimes needs a lot of space in /tmp and throws this error when there is not enough space there. You can alleviate that problem by creating a folder on some very big volume and issuing: export TMPDIR=/path/to/massive/volume/tmp

Comment: Yes, the volume contains backups exclusively. And I don't think the temporary directory has anything to do with it (yet I still tried to change it and it failed).

Answer (score 1):

Other than growing the underlying filesystem, there isn't a good way, but that should be pretty easy — you have many options there, including getting a new, larger drive and mirroring the data over (using something like `cp -a` or `rsync -a`). The annoyance with large backup volumes is that this can take a very long time.

If you are like me and have multiple backups on the same filesystem, you can easily find space by moving a backup or large file somewhere else temporarily.

To avoid this problem, I have learned to leave a `.00DOORSTOP` file in my backup directory that I can `rm` when I need the space. I currently have the file at 1GB, which should be enough to allow me to create more space if needed — rdiff-backup needs a minimal amount of space to run (probably to create temporary files). It can't be a sparse file, obviously; I create it by using `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=.00DOORSTOOP bs=1G count=1
```